# Python reshape list that has no exact square root

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to reshape a numpy array with a length of 155369 using `numpy.reshape` but since 155369 has no exact square root we round it down and the reshape function gives an error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 155369 into shape (394, 394)`

```py
size = int(numpy.sqrt(index))
reshaped = numpy.reshape(data[:index], (size, size))
```

How can this array be reshaped correctly?

Comment: well, you cannot. Think how would you reshape an array of 10 elements into a 3x3 matrix. You have 3 options: Reshape into a 4x4 matrix and fill the extra elements with some toy value. 2) Discard elements from your matrix until it has size 9 or 3) Don't reshape into a square matrix, but a 5x2 matrix instead (or the combination of factors that gets closer to a square)

Comment: Get rid of additional entries manually, then reshape. Numpy is intelligent, it won't let you lose data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either to [`pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) your array:

```
a = np.ones(155369, dtype=int)

n = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(a.size)))

b = np.pad(a, (0, n**2-a.size), mode='constant', constant_values=0).reshape(n, n)

b.shape
# (395, 395)
```

Or to drop extra values:

```
a = np.ones(155369, dtype=int)

n = int(np.sqrt(a.size))

b = a[:n**2].reshape(n, n)

b.shape
# (394, 394)
```

Example with a input array of 13 elements:

```
# input
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13])

# padding
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13,  0,  0,  0]])

# dropping extra
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```